Determine the number of subgroups of order $9$ in the alternating group $6$
Using Sylow's theorem, I found that all possible cases are $1, 4, 10,$ and $40,$ but I can only conclude that $1$ is not possible. How can I determine that $4, 10,$ and $40$ are not possible?

We can list $10$ such subgroups, namely Sylow $3$-subgroups, of order $9$:
$$
U_1=\langle (123),(456) \rangle, U_2=\langle (124),(356) \rangle, U_1=\langle (125),(346) \rangle, U_4=\langle (126),(345) \rangle, U_5=\langle (134),(256) \rangle, \ldots, U_{10}=\langle (156),(234) \rangle.
$$
We can rule out $40$, because then the $3$-subgroup would be self-normalizing. But a group of order $9$ is abelian, and hence by Burnside's Transfer Theorem, then $A_6$ would not be simple, a contradiction.
Hence we have $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}=10$ such $3$-Sylow subgroups.

Alternatively, instead of quoting Burnside, it is enough to observe $U_1$ is normalized by the element $(14)(25)(36)(23) = (14)(2635)$ of order $4$.

You can also avoid the transfer theorem by noting $40\neq 1\pmod{9}$, so there are two Sylows intersecting in a subgroup of order $3$. This subgroup would have a very large normalizer (contradicting simplicity of $A_6$).

Such a group is conjugate to $\langle (123),(456)\rangle$. (By Sylow's Theorem, for example.) You can just count these groups directly: each group is equivalent to a partition of a $6$-set into two $3$-sets, and there are $\binom{6}{3}/2=10$ of these.
A more general comment: the modular restriction on the number of Sylow subgroups from the third Sylow Theorem is most useful when you know little about the group, just its order for example. If you have a concrete group, it's often easier to determine the number directly somehow rather than trying to rule out the possibilities given by that theorem.
